# Pandas - map one column to another and apply multiplication on row

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({target:[0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
                   points:[5.0, 2.5, 3.6})
```

And I need to get the lowest 'target' value (other than 0) and multiply 'points' by 2 on the respective row.

Ending up with:

```
target points
0.0      5.0
1.0      5.0
2.0      3.6
```

How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `idxmin` and `loc`:

```
idx = df[df['target']!=0]['target'].idxmin()
                
df['points'].loc[idx] = df['points'].loc[idx] * 2
```